# Protractor on AngularJS - 'script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds' after login page change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

Protractor hangs completely when trying to get any element property after logging in (idk if it's related to logging in or related just to switching pages).

```
it("Should get location of main container", async function() {
    await LoginPage.validLogin();
    // Works and logs in the dashboard
    await browser.sleep(3000);
    // Get the main container by class name
    const container = await element(by.css(".main-container"));
    // Logs properly the element functions (as expected)
    console.log(container);
    console.log(await container.getLocation()); // Hangs here
});
```

In this case, I'm trying to get the location of the main container element on the page. The first console.log fires and shows properly, while the second hangs completely, so I get the script timeout. Increasing the timeout time doesn't help at all...

I found online that misusing $timeout in AngularJS instead of using $interval may lead to this strange behaviour, but I really can't skim through the entire (very big!) project's codebase to change everything hoping that it just works, not to talk about the external libraries using $timeout.

I have SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER = false; in my Protractor config so I disabled the built-in Control Flow in order to manually manage the promises using async/await, but even if I use the built-in Control Flow without using async/await I get the very same behaviour and error.
I'm using Jasmine as testing framework.

Maybe I'm missing something? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the fact that angular is not stable. Have a look at the link below. I found my answer there. When the page you are trying to test is open go to the browser dev tools and type in the console `getAllAngularTestabilities()`. There are a few properties here that indicate whether angular is ready to be tested. `hasPendingMicrotasts` needs to be false. `hasPendingMacroTasks` needs to be false. `isStable` needs to be true. I put a screenshot below. In my screenshot `hasPendingMacrotasks` is true and it must be false. So the page I looked at was not ready to be tested.

[Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, #my-btn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240582/failed-script-timeout-result-was-not-received-in-11-seconds-from-task-protra)

[image: console. My page is not ready for testing]

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
it("Should get location of main container", async function() {
    await LoginPage.validLogin();
    const container = await element(by.css(".main-container"));
    await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(container), 5000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
    await console.log(await container.getLocation());
});
```

Comment: It still goes 'Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds'... I have no idea at this point

Comment: There is no getLocation() function in the JS bindings!  You can use getRect() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `getLocation()` exists in the *Javascript* bindings for selenium.  I couldn't find it in the source code anyway.  So that promise will never return which is why it hangs.  But I the you can achieve basically the same thing with `getRect()`:

```
it("Should get location of main container", async function() {
    await LoginPage.validLogin();
    const container = await element(by.css(".main-container"));
    await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(container), 5000, 'Element taking too long to appear in the DOM');
    await console.log(await container.getRect());
});
```

Comment: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getLocation